# Existence of an integer $k$ whose square $k^2$ is the average of two consecutive primes with a gap of size $8$ between them.

Tags: square-numbers, prime-gaps

It can be seen that the average of two consecutive primes with a gap of size $8$ between them is odd.  If this average is $k^2$, then we may assume it ends with a digit $1, 5,$ or $9$. But $1$ and $9$ are discounted because adding or subtracting $8/2=4$ to or from the average will result in either of the two numbers ending with $5$, so both of them cannot be prime. Therefore the average $k^2$ itself must end with the digit $5$, and so must $k$ also.

Is there such integer $k$ that $k^2$ is the average of two consecutive primes with a gap of size $8$ between them?

Comment: The lower of the candidate primes would be $k^2-4 = (k+2)(k-2)$, wouldn't it, assuming I've understood the claim properly?

Comment: Yes, Brian, that is right. And the greater of the candidate primes is k^2 + 4. I wonder if such k exists at all...

Comment: I'm not sure I expressed myself clearly enough; doesn't it seem as though the lower candidate can never actually be a prime, because it factors as $(k+2)(k-2)$?

Comment: @BrianTung:  this argument could fail for $k=3$ because then $k-2=1$ but $3$ and $11$ are not consecutive primes.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Yes, sorry, I should've said that the small cases of $k$ should be handled individually, and then larger values can be handled by my observation. I was being a little telegraphic in a comment. :-)

Comment: @BrianTung   It is just that one because you need to make sure both factors are greater than $1$.  I was writing more for OP than you.

Comment: I've filled in the details in an answer.

Comment: However, for all even gaps that are *not* twice a square, this appears to be doable. $2^2$ gets us $3$ and $5$; $3^2$ gets us $7$ and $11$; $8^2$ gives us $61$ and $67$; $12^2$ gets us $139$ and $149$, etc. The first $10000$ perfect squares give us examples of every even gap up to $66$ (except for $8$, $18$, $32$, $50$).

Comment: Thank you, Misha. Exactly these k's and prime gaps I was investigating. Those even gaps that are twice a square cannot have a square right in the middle, by Brian's factoring trick: k^2 - 9 = (k+3)(k−3), k^2 - 16 = (k+4)(k−4), etc. And I knew this in the school many years ago! :-)

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

For any $k$, the candidate primes would be $k^2-4$ and $k^2+4$. For $k = 1$ and $k = 2$, the lower candidate is too small; for $k = 3$, the candidates are $5$ and $13$, which are both primes, but not consecutive; and for $k \geq 4$, the lower candidate factors as $k^2-4 = (k-2)(k+2)$, and is therefore not prime.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I've long been in school but now I see and can grasp your nice proof.